# How can we evaluate the performance of Eucalyptus

Tags: cloud, amazon-cloudfront, rackspace-cloud, eucalyptus, ycsb

How can we evaluate the performance of Eucalyptus. Is there a tool that can collect statistics about the same?

thanks

Comment: what you want to exactly evaluate ?

Answer (score 3):

At least for the S3 Walrus part of Eucalyptus, YCSB (Yahoo! Cloud Serving Benchmark) https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB has been a very useful tool.  You can write custom drivers for S3 operations PUT, GET, DELETE, LIST.  Then YCSB enables easy setup and testing that reports latency, errors, and other statistics for a performance analysis.

Some excellent information and resources about EC2 testing in these links:

Even Stranger than Expected: a Systematic Look at EC2 I/O
http://blog.scalyr.com/2012/10/16/a-systematic-look-at-ec2-io/

EC2 Benchmark Followup (Source + Data)
http://blog.scalyr.com/2012/10/29/ec2-benchmark-followup-source-data/

Answer (score 0):

CPU & Disk: You can run any local benchmark tools, as long as it can run in a virtual environment. 
- You can enable-disable VT-d between the tests to see the impact.

Network: You can also run network benchmarks using different configurations:
- Two instances on the same node
- '' on two different nodes
- '' on two different clusters
- '' with one outside of the cloud

GPU: This is still pretty experimental.  You'll have to find recipes on the web (very rare).